# object created from contrctor returns object with constructor name, but no colon

Tags: javascript

I'm using a constructor, then with the object created form a construct, I change the values based on certain conditonals -- then return it.

However, When I return the new Object, it includes the original constructor's name, but without any colons. I am not able to access the data.

```js
    function constructorFunction(name, count){
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    function conditionalFunction(a, b){
      var conditional = new constructorFunction(a, b);
    
     if (b > 1){
        conditional.count = b * 2;
    }
      return conditional;
    }


(function () {
var neededData = conditionalFunction('bob', 33);

console.log('neededData :', neededData);
})();
```

returns an object with the original constructor name, but no semi colons.. :

```
conditionalFunction {name: 'name', count: 2}.
```

I'm expecting it to return just the JSON object: {name: name, count: 2}, but i'm getting  this returned conditionalFunction {name: name, count: 2}

There is no colon. conditionalFunction is not recognized as a property, so I cannot access the data within the object by trying something like:

```
neededData.constructorFunction = undefined
```

Comment: hey @someoneHere can you post JSFiddle running code link here so that I can help you easily

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: hmm? one is the function definition, the other is the json representation of the instance object -- what are you expecting to see and where does the return object representation you show come from?

Comment: Still don't understand your question?

Comment: can you explain a bit more

Comment: I updated it, but it seems to be working correctly within this snipet. Not sure what's going on..

Comment: are you sure there's nothing overwriting? I created a pen with this and works flawlessly

Comment: neededData.constructorFunction = undefined 
I got your problem, actually you are confused in OOP, you need to better understand how objects work

Comment: neededData.constructorFunction = undefined 
** in this line it is clear that you are trying to access constructorFunction using neededData obeject, where actually neededData has nothing to do with constructorFunction **

Comment: you can access count and name using neededData

Comment: @Muhammad No. I don't think you understand. For some reason, in my production code, the function returns this --> constructorFunction {name: 'name', count: 2} . 

An object with constructor name before it. However, that constructor name is not a property. I cannot access the data within the JSON. 

Not sure how to word it better.. 

However, it seems to be working within the snippet above...

Comment: It's not clear at all if you are talking about the representation of an object in JSON, your browser's console, stack snippet's console, or something else.

Comment: Sorry, @oriol  someone else added the stack snippet, which made my initial question unclear. I've asked for this to be deleted by mods.

Comment: You can always edit your post. I don't understand what semicolon are you talking about.

Answer (score 0):

1. neededData is a referenced object to constructorFunction
2. constructorFunction is not a variable or property of neededData
3. properties of constructorFunction are name and count
4. therefore properties of neededData are also name and count

neededData.constructorFunction = undefined

in this line it is clear that you are trying to access constructorFunction using neededData object,
Actually neededData object has a reference to constructorFunction, so you can access constructorFunction's name and count attributes using neededData object like:

```js
 function constructorFunction(name, count){
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    function conditionalFunction(a, b){
      var conditional = new constructorFunction(a, b);
    
     if (b > 1){
        conditional.count = b * 2;
    }
      return conditional;
    }


(function () {
var neededData = conditionalFunction('bob', 33);

console.log('name using neededData object:', neededData.name);
  console.log('count using neededData object:', neededData.count);
})();
```

Comment: I hope now you will understand where you are making mistake

Comment: please don't hesitate to ask anything

Comment: No. I only attempted to access neededData.constructorFunction = undefined , because for some reason in my production code i'm getting this when I console.log neededData --> constructorFunction {'name': 'bob', 'count': 66}

I initially thought it was returning needed data as an object with constructor function nested within it. But, it's not. I cannot access the data. 

there is no colon after constructor function, it is not a property.

Comment: You can see that your developer console is showing you the name of actual object that is constructorFunction and not the reference object that is neededData

Comment: Yes that is what i am saying constructorFunction is not a property of neededData object, so you cannot access constructorFunction using this :neededData.constructorFunction

Comment: yes, I know. But, why in my production code would needData = constructorFunction {'name': name, 'count' count} ?

Comment: needData = constructorFunction {'name': name, 'count' count}--------- first of all this is not a production code, it is a console toolbar for helping developers to see their variables and objects in realtime

Comment: needData = constructorFunction {'name': name, 'count' count}---------this line means that there is an object in memory named constructorFunction which has two properties, one is name and other is count, but constructorFunction itself is not a property

Comment: and constructorFunction = neededData clearly means that neededData is a reference object to actual object constructorFunction.

Comment: means both have different names but same data ]

Comment: and remember this is not a json until you specifically use JSON.stringify(neededData); function

Comment: Wouldn't that convert JSON to a string.. ?

Comment: Something else is causing this. Possibly something in node. I really appreciate your effort in help. This question should probably be deleted, as it's not much use to the community.  the only way around this for me was to return {name:  conditionalFunction.name, 'count': conditionalFunction.count}

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your constructor to this:

```
function constructorFunction(name, count){
  return {name:name,count:count};
}
```